# ternary string that contains only $0's$, $1's$, and $2's$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

A string that contains only  $0's$, $1's$, and $2's$ is called a ternary string.
(a) Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings that do not contain
two consecutive $0's$. 
(b) What are the initial conditions ? 
(c) How many ternary strings of length six do not contain two consecutive $0's$?

for answer a)
Let $a_n$ be the number of ternary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two
consecutive $0's$. In order to construct a bit string of length $n$ of this type, we
could start with a $1$ or $2$ and follow with a string of length $n−1$ not containing
two consecutive $0’s$, or we could start with $01$ or $02$ and follow with a string
of length $n − 2$ not containing two consecutive $0's$. Consequently, we have the
recurrence relation: $a_n = 2a_{n−1} + 2a_{n−2}$.

for answer b)
$a_0 = 0$ (for the empty string), $ a_1 = 3$ (all three strings of length 1 fail to contain
two consecutive $0's$).

and Do a and b have a correct answer?and could you help me with( c),I do not know how can I answer it

Thank you

Comment: But $a_2 = 8 = \left|\{01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22\}\right|$...

Comment: As for part c, once you are comfortable with your recursion you can just use it to compute $a_6$.  As a rule, it's tricky to rely on $a_0$ to start the recursion off.  Here, $a_0$ ought to be $1$ but it seems more intuitive to compute $a_1,a_2$ by hand and go from there.

Comment: a2 = 2a1 + 2a0 = 8;
a3 = 2a2 + 2a1 = 22;
a4 = 2a3 + 2a2 = 60;
a5 = 2a4 + 2a3 = 164;
a6 = 2a5 + 2a4 = 448;

Comment: a0=1, a1=3 is it correct?